# Select dropdown is not selecting ng-model with ng-options

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-1.5

Very new to angular and currently stock in something

I have a dropdown that is set up like this

```html
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in templateCtrl.template.templateDetails">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="item.categoryID" ng-options="category.categoryName for category in templateCtrl.categories track by category.categoryID"></select>
</div>
```

It populates the dropdown but item.categoryID (all values are 1) is not selected. Help on this matter will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix a few things in your `<select>` element:
use `category.id as category.name` in your ng-options.

```
ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in templateCtrl.categories track by category.categoryID"
```

If you want one of the options to be pre selected when loading the page or view you can do it with `ng-init`. In there you can set the model of that select to the value that has to be selected.

Comment: That will display the category id as options. I want my value to be the category id but the text should be the name